# Hover Jquery not working a second time for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Matrix made of a Table, i am creating code to select a range of these `TD`, `onmousedown` i am selecting the `start` and marking the `TR` (so i know the row im in) this so the selection can be done in that row only, then with `hover` i am marking the `TD` between the `start` and `end` `TD's`, its working like this:

[image]

- **Green**: the row where the selection is taking place
- **Yellow**: start TD
- **Red**: end TD
- **Blue**: TD's between start and end

My issue its that when i click again in the "selecting row" the cursor changes and the hover doesnt work, the mousedown works since the `TD` i click on turns `yellow` but i go to the left in the row (holding the click) and nothing happens.

[image]

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Angeltouch/bcp01z59/123/) with it, i created a HTML page locally as well but the same happens, to reproduce go to the fiddle select a range, then in the same row try to select again.

Comment: Didn't figure it out yet, but it seems to work OK if you click twice on another td after the first time

Comment: for me it doesnt work a second time in any row that i already selected, the cursos changes to the cancel icon itw weird and its driving me crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is not firing the `mouseup` event after being clicked for the second time (if the element was hovered on).

The issue is solved when adding `e.preventDefault()` to your mousedown event.

Comment: i will be dammed i think i focused so much in everything else i didnt think of the basics